# Why react - i18next library doesn't work on my project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I implemented i18next library for my project but I couldn't run it. I gave example code scripts in below. I want to try the library on CreateEmployeeComponent page. How can I fix it ?

index.js page is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import i18n from 'i18next';
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next'
import en from './en';
import tr from './tr';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

const resources ={
  'en-Us' : en,
  'tr-TR' : tr
};

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  resources,
  lng: 'tr-TR',
  keySeparator : false,
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue : false
  }
})


export default {i18n, initReactI18next, useTranslation}

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js page is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import ListEmployeeComponent from './components/ListEmployeeComponent';
import HeaderComponent from './components/HeaderComponent';
import FooterComponent from './components/FooterComponent';
import CreateEmployeeComponent from './components/CreateEmployeeComponent';
import ViewEmployeeComponent from './components/ViewEmployeeComponent';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';


function App() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <div>
        <Router>
              <HeaderComponent />
                <div className="container">
                    <Router> 
                          <Route path = "/" exact component = {ListEmployeeComponent}></Route>
                          <Route path = "/employees" component = {ListEmployeeComponent}></Route>
                          <Route path = "/add-employee/:id" component = {CreateEmployeeComponent}></Route>
                          <Route path = "/view-employee/:id" component = {ViewEmployeeComponent}></Route>
                    </Router>
                </div>
              <FooterComponent />
        </Router>
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

I imported useTranslation in CreateEmployeeComponent.js page.The page create a emplooye save form. Example screenshot given in below. The page is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import EmployeeService from '../services/EmployeeService';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';



class CreateEmployeeComponent extends Component {
    
    errors = {};
    isValidEmail = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/g;

    constructor(props) {

        super(props)


        this.state = {
            // step 2
            id: this.props.match.params.id,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            emailId: ''

        }
        this.changeFirstNameHandler = this.changeFirstNameHandler.bind(this);
        this.changeLastNameHandler = this.changeLastNameHandler.bind(this);
        this.saveOrUpdateEmployee = this.saveOrUpdateEmployee.bind(this);
    }

    isValidEmail = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/g;
    componentDidMount(){


        if(this.state.id === '_add'){
            return
        }else{
            EmployeeService.getEmployeeById(this.state.id).then( (res) =>{
                let employee = res.data;
                this.setState({firstName: employee.firstName,
                    lastName: employee.lastName,
                    emailId : employee.emailId
                });
            });
        }        
    }

    
    saveOrUpdateEmployee = (e) => {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        if(this.state.firstName ==='' || this.state.firstName===null) {
            alert("Please enter your first name");
        }

        else if(!this.state.firstName.match(/^[a-zA-ZİöÖğĞüÜşŞçÇ]+$/)){
            alert("First name can only contain letters");
        }
        else if(this.state.firstName.length<3){
            alert("Your Frist name should contain at least 3 characters");
        }
        else if(this.state.lastName ==='' || this.state.lastName===null){
            alert("Please enter your last name");
        }
        else if(!this.state.lastName.match(/^[a-zA-ZİöÖğĞüÜşŞçÇ]+$/)){
            alert("Last name can only contain letters");
        }
        else if(this.state.lastName.length<3){
            alert("Your last name should contain at least 3 characters");
        }
        else if(this.state.emailId ==='' || this.state.emailId===null){
            alert("Please enter your email");
        }

        else if(!this.state.emailId.match(this.isValidEmail)) {
            alert("Please enter your email");
        }

        else  {
        let employee = {firstName: this.state.firstName, lastName: this.state.lastName, emailId: this.state.emailId};
        console.log('employee => ' + JSON.stringify(employee));


        if(this.state.id === '_add'){
            EmployeeService.createEmployee(employee).then(res =>{
                this.props.history.push('/employees');
            });
        }else{
            EmployeeService.updateEmployee(employee, this.state.id).then( res => {
                this.props.history.push('/employees');
            });
        }
    }
    }
    
    changeFirstNameHandler= (event) => {
        this.setState({firstName: event.target.value});
    }

    changeLastNameHandler= (event) => {
        this.setState({lastName: event.target.value});
    }

    changeEmailHandler= (event) => {
        this.setState({emailId: event.target.value});
    }

    cancel(){
        this.props.history.push('/employees');
    }

    getTitle(){
        if(this.state.id === '_add'){
            return <h3 className="text-center">Add Employee</h3>
        }else{
            return <h3 className="text-center">Update Employee</h3>
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <br></br>
                   <div className = "container">
                        <div className = "row">
                            <div className = "card col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-md-3">
                                {
                                    this.getTitle()
                                }
                                <div className = "card-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> First Name: </label>
                                            <input placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.changeFirstNameHandler}/>

                                        </div>
                                        <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> Last Name: </label>
                                            <input placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.changeLastNameHandler}/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> Email Id: </label>
                                            <input placeholder="Email Address" name="emailId" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.emailId} onChange={this.changeEmailHandler}/>
                                        </div>

                                        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.saveOrUpdateEmployee}>Save</button>
                                        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.cancel.bind(this)} style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}>Cancel</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                   </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default CreateEmployeeComponent
```

[employee save page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88q1P.png)

tr.js and en.js pages given below.

tr.js page is below:

```
export default {
    translation : {
        "First Name" : "Isim"
    }
}
```

en.js page is below:

```
export default {
    translation : {
        "Isim" : "First Name"
    }
}
```

These en.js and tr.js examples are written to check whether the library is working or not.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting to happen here. You havn't actually used the `t` function to translate anything.

Comment: Follow this guide and afterwards compare it with your code: https://locize.com/blog/react-i18next/

Comment: I already did by looking at this but I couldn't run it. Sorry, your solution is not explanatory. @adrai

Comment: Just tried the linked example provided by the guide: https://github.com/locize/react-i18next-example-app/tree/i18next and it seems to work